# Clean install of Win10 (free upgrade version)

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, windows-update, boot-camp, license-key

I have Parallels running on my Mac, several years ago I got a copy of Windows 8 on disc from which I set up a VM. In time this was upgraded to Win 8.1 and Win 10, all within the VM.

I want to get rid of the VM and either start a clean one - maybe not in Parallels - or install using BootCamp on the same Mac.

But as far as I know, the only product key and downloaded install media I have are the original Windows 8 ones. Is this going to be possible, e.g. can I still find a Win10 download? I'd rather not re-install Win8 and let it update, is this even possible anyway?

Comment: Do you want VM? Here is a ready-made one https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/

Comment: They're browser VMs, 90-day expiry.

Comment: @Tetsujin One can take a snapshot in first run then recreate it after 90 days.

Comment: if you upgraded the VM from 8 to 10, only the digital usage right of Windows 10 is only allowed for this VM no separate partition.

Answer (score 1):

You won't have received a full product key as part of the upgrade, nor do you officially have one for Win10, its linked to your microsoft account and hardware ID.

Microstft state:
"The Windows 10 free upgrade through the Get Windows 10 (GWX) app ended on July 29, 2016."

So you wont be able to install 8 and upgrade to 10 again.

However...
According to Microsoft: "After you upgrade to Windows 10, you can reinstall or do a clean installation on the same device. You won't need a product key to reactivate Windows 10 on the same hardware."

Is this going to work within a VM? Good question... I think unlikely, but please try!

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/12435/windows-10-upgrade-faq

Answer (score 0):

You can easily obtain the Windows 10 ISO file directly from Microsoft  - [Download Windows 10 Disc Image (ISO File)](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10ISO)

However, your options on that page are different depending on whether you access it from a Mac or Windows.
On Mac you only get the option to download the ISO...

[image]

On Windows you get the option to "create install media" on a bootable USB key.

[image]

Whether you need the ISO or the boot key will depend on your intended method for the new install - Boot Camp, Parallels, other VM etc..
Having both of these keeps your options open.

So, before you disassemble your existing setup, get the boot key made.

Your existing licence would only carry to a new Parallels VM, but as Win10 will run quite happily without being activated - it removes some options, mainly cosmetic - you can decide on your licence model later.

Something that may be worth trying - I've never tested it - but if you wanted to keep using Parallels, duplicate the existing VM for safety & then see if you can reset the Windows 10 installation already on it [the USB key or ISO may come in handy for this, I'm not sure.]